# Display product category taxonomy terms in WooCommerce shop loop

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am looking to display a list of product categories in the shop loop.

Parent Term | Child Term | Child Term

I have tried wp_list_categories() but this breaks the links and puts in duplicates of the product links in the

```
<ul>
<a href="example.com/product/bb-glow/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"> </a>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-39">
<a href="example.com/product/bb-glow/" class="woocommerce-LoopProduct-link woocommerce-loop-product__link"></a>
<a href="example.com/product-category/online-courses/">Online Courses</a>
    <ul class="children">
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-43"><a href="example.com/product-category/online-courses/micropigmentation/">Micropigmentation</a>
        </li>
        <li class="cat-item cat-item-37"><a href="example.com/product-category/online-courses/semi-permanent-makeup/">Semi-permanent Makeup</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi, just a heads up. A lot of the community consider woo-commerce to be off-topic. You might get some answers but they will likely be a bit slow.